# When I enter an input using command line tool in Xcode, the code ignores it the first time I enter it. Why is this and is there a way to avoid it?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

I am a newbie to Xcode and am learning C using the command line tool. Often when I write a program and enter an input, the code will not execute for the first time I enter it, however once this first input is ignored, the code executes exactly as expected. I was just wondering why this is? Am I doing something wrong when I'm writing my code or is this just something that happens in Xcode?

Example of code that this occurs in (this is something that I had to do for college. It reads an input "celsius=[something]" and displays a chart showing the conversion from celsius to fahrenheit and makes comments on it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int start;
    int celsius;
    float fahrenheit;

    scanf("celsius=%d\n", &start);

    if(start<0||start>100)
    {
            printf("The value entered should be in the right range\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Celsius | Fahrenheit | comment\n");
        printf("------------------------------\n");

        for(celsius=start;celsius<=100;celsius=celsius+20)
        {
            fahrenheit=celsius*(9.0/5.0)+32;
            printf("   %d   |   %.2f   |", celsius, fahrenheit);

            if(fahrenheit==32.0)
            {
                printf("  Freezing point\n");
            }
            else if(fahrenheit>=64.0&&fahrenheit<=77.0)
            {
                printf("  Room temperature\n");
            }
            else if(fahrenheit>=122.0&&fahrenheit<=176.0)
            {
                printf("  Hot bath\n");
            }
            else if(fahrenheit==212.0)
            {
                printf("  Water boils\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format string supplied in `scanf()` needs to have the exact same input to be a *match*. In your case

```
  scanf("celsius=%d\n", &start);
```

is creating the *problem*, it expects an input which consists of

- `celsius=` string
- and integer value
- one (or more) `whitespace`

and another `newline`, to terminate the input. So, finally you need two <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press to match the criteria. First keypress produces a `newline` which matches the requirement of the whitespace and second time, it produces another newline, which terminates the input.

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2,

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the
>   first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can
>   be read. [...]

You need to reduce it to

```
 scanf("celsius=%d", &start);  //remove the trailing `\n`
```

and check for the return value of `scanf()` to ensure success.